# Sql Statement Custom Class

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, class

I am new to programming, I tried to create a sub that contains a SQL statement in it using parameterized query. My code is not working, there might something lacking to it or am I doing it wrong.

My connection string is in the `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name = "DBCS"
           connectionString ="Data Source=Mic-PC\Developer; Initial Catalog=Customer; User Id = sa; Password=1224334;"
           providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I create a class called `SELECTCLASS` and here is the content

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SelectClass

Public Sub searchData(search As String, LastName As String, FirstName As String, MiddleInitial As String, Age As String, Address As String)

    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ConnectionString

    Using con As New SqlConnection(CS)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spGetCustomerByName", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Storedprocedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "%" + search + "%")
        con.Open()

        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                While rdr.Read()
                    LastName = rdr.GetString(1).ToString
                    FirstName = rdr.GetString(2).ToString
                    MiddleInitial = rdr.GetString(3).ToString
                    Age = rdr.GetString(4).ToString
                    Address = rdr.GetString(5).ToString
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the code for my Windows Form:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SELECTVB

Dim SelectData As New SelectClass

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
    SelectData.searchData(txtsearch.Text, TextBox1.Text.ToString, TextBox2.Text.ToString, TextBox3.Text.ToString, TextBox4.Text.ToString, TextBox5.Text.ToString)
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: include your stored procedure as well. the parameter sent in for LIKE statement shouln't works that way

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it an exception or simply no results?

Comment: It will not return any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see two problem with your code, neither of which have anything to do with ADO or SQL.  The problems are related to the way that the data that is read from the database is being passed back to the calling method.  I suspect that the `searchData` method is successfully reading the data from the query results (though you would need to confirm this using the debugger by setting a break-point, stepping through the method, and inspecting the variables' values).

The first problem I see is that you are passing the result of the `TextBox.Text.ToString` method rather than the `TextBox.Text` property itself.  In other words, you should be calling the `searchData` method like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
    SelectData.searchData(txtsearch.Text, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
End Sub
```

Secondly, you are attempting to reassign the reference of those `Text` arguments from inside the `searchData` method, but the parameters are not declared `ByRef`.  If you want to do it that way, you would need to change the parameters of the method to `ByRef`, like this:

```
Public Sub searchData(search As String, ByRef LastName As String, ByRef FirstName As String, ByRef MiddleInitial As String, ByRef Age As String, ByRef Address As String)
```

However, none of that would be a problem if you returned the results via the function's return value rather than changing the values of the parameters.  Most developers, including myself, discourage using `ByRef` parameters in this manner because it's unexpected behavior.  Typically parameters should be reserved for inputs rather than outputs.  For instance, if you created a class like this:

```
Public Class Customer
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property MiddleInitial As String
    Public Property Age As String
    Public Property Address As String
End Class
```

Then you could change your search method to return a `Customer` object, like this:

```
Public Function SearchData(search As String) As Customer
    Dim result As Customer = Nothing
    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCS").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(CS)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spGetCustomerByName", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Storedprocedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "%" & search & "%")
            con.Open()
            Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If rdr.HasRows Then
                    If rdr.Read() Then
                        result = New Customer()
                        result.LastName = rdr.GetString(1)
                        result.FirstName = rdr.GetString(2)
                        result.MiddleInitial = rdr.GetString(3)
                        result.Age = rdr.GetString(4)
                        result.Address = rdr.GetString(5)
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Sub
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
    Dim c As Customer = SelectData.searchData(txtsearch.Text)
    If c IsNot Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Text = c.LastName
        TextBox2.Text = c.FirstName
        TextBox3.Text = c.MiddleInitial
        TextBox4.Text = c.Age
        TextBox5.Text = c.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

However, given the context of what you are doing, it seems likely that your method ought to be returning a list of customers rather than just a single one.

If making these changes still does not fix the problem, stepping through the search method with the debugger will be your best chance of solving the problem.  It could be that the stored procedure is returning no matches, or it's returning a different number of columns than you are expecting, or it could be returning a column with a data-type other than a string (like the age column might be an integer, for instance).  It's impossible to say, given only the information that you've provided, what the precise problem with the data access code would be.